# view image in a small part of window in qt

Tags: c++, image, qt

I know how to view a image in the full window from [Qt jpg image display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357960/qt-jpg-image-display) but I need to display the image 200x300px size. that means I need the program to read the jpg image and rezise it and view it in a small box placed in the side of the window. I dont have eny idea which widget I should place for this and the method to do this. can somebody point out me some tutorial or give in simple advice.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you load the image, for example:

```
QImage img;
img.loadFromData(data);
```

use QImage::scaled() to create a scaled copy of it and assign it to itself. Example:

```
img = img.scaled(200, 300, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

Adjust the flags as preferred (see the QImage::scaled() documentation on the available flags.)

You can then display it. The easiest way is to set it as a pixmap on a QLabel:

```
QLabel label;
label.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

You might want to set a fixed size for the QLabel, but this depends on how you handle your overall layout in your application.

Comment: @UmNyobe Welcome to the club ;-)

Comment: I can add that fixing the size of the label may be required, otherwise re-sizing the window will re-size the label (thus the image displayed)

Comment: @UmNyobe Can't QLabel::setScaledContents(false) be used for this? (Which is false by default anyway.)

Comment: you are right with the image not being re-sized, but there is also layout issues.

Comment: i replaced `img.loadFromData(data);` with `img.loadFromData("test.jpg"); now make it little more clear how to view it.

Comment: Im new in qt. I need help. what widget I should place to view the image in.

Comment: @LakshanPerera As written in the answer: a QLabel.

Comment: I need the image appear on a button click. so I add the code in a slot function. is their a mistake. I get this error

Comment: error: request for member 'setPixmap' in '((MainWindow*)this)->MainWindow::<anonymous>.Ui::MainWindow::<anonymous>.Ui_MainWindow::label', which is of non-class type 'QLabel*'

Comment: @LakshanPerera You should read a Qt tutorial on how widgets work. I can't teach you Qt on StackOverflow :-/