# How to display an image with Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, widget

Looking through the widgets supplied by Qt, it seems there isn't one for displaying images. What is the proper way to display an image in Qt?

Comment: take a look at [Stackoverflow question 1357960](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357960/qt-jpg-image-display)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt jpg image display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357960/qt-jpg-image-display)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There isn't a widget specifically made for displaying images, but this can be done with the label widget. We do this with the pixmap property.

In your code, make sure you include

```
#include <QPixmap>
```

Then, wherever you wish to set the image, include the following

```
QPixmap pic("/path/to/your/image");
ui->label->setPixmap(pic);
```

What we do here is create a QPixmap object, which serves as an image, and then set that object to the pixmap property of the label.

Comment: `QGraphicsView` has much more possibilities if one want such (scroll bars, rotation, etc).